# Cooldown php json

Tags: php, вконтакте, api

Как через json можно сделать cooldown?
Например у меня есть бот ВКонтакте, и команда "бонус", мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при второй отправке команды "бонус" пользователю отправлялось сообщение "Подождите 4 часа"! Как можно сделать такую задержку?

```
                    elseif($body[0] == 'бонус' || $body[0] == 'Бонус'){
                    $from_id = $this->conf->data->object->from_id;
                    $UserData = json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'), true);
                    if(!isset($UserData[$from_id]['bonus'])){
                        $UserData[$from_id]['balance'] += 3500;
                        $UserData[$from_id]['bonus'] = 'used';
                        file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($UserData));
                        $self = "$nick".", \n\n✅Вы получили бонус 3500$! Баланс: {$UserData[$from_id]['balance']}$";
                    }else{
                        $self = "$nick".", \n\n❎Вы уже использовали бонус!";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Непонятно что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Хочу задержку сделать, что не понятного?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php

Comment: Сохраните в базе данных дату-время последнего "бонуса" пользователю. И при запросе проверяйте – если 4 часа не прошло, то ничего не давайте.

Comment: Можно в коде пожалуйста? Я изучаю php не больше 2 недель.